# JMETER + query regarding Mysql database

Tags: mysql, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using wordpress application and running Jmeter to perform load test on "wordpress" app.
When I am creating a blog, I capture through JMETER via proxy and 1 blog is created, with a new record in mysql database say id is 2.

When I run again the same suite of jmeter, I get the results but new records are not added to mysql still the same id 2 is used.

If I say no of threads as 2 and loop count as 1, will 2 new records be added to MYSQL?
I don't see this happening.
Just need some clarification on this.

Comment: any feedback, if answer is ok, you should accept it so that it helps others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes 2 records should be created.
Once you record, you need to variabilize what is dynamic before replaying, to do that you typically use Regular Expression Extractor to extract the id for example and can then use it with ${}

Comment: Thank you, I am recording the http requests using "Recoding controller" and it's capturing login, create blog, publish blog and log out request. When Again I run the thread it runs successfully and there is no error in "View result" tree all threads have executed successfully but  there is no record added to Mysql database. I am not sure what exactly the prob is.

Comment: As I answered , there are some IDs that need to be variabilized, unless you do it it will always fail.

Comment: Hi, I am also using Jmeter to do some performance testing on my local copy of wordpress site. I however notice that it doesn't pass through the login stage. I use the the test recorder to record the actions but when I run it, it doesn't login. So I will suggest you check if it actually logs in and if it does, I will like to know what you did about that as I am currently stuck in that stage